# DateTime and Ticks in Jython

Tags: date, time, jython-2.5

How should I write the following C# .NET code in Jython?

```
ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
```

I am new to Jython and I use Jython-2.2.1 in nGrinder version 3.0 and JDK version 1.7.0_10.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need those ticks? Is it for some reporting for example to show how many ticks elapsed between two events?

This C# code shows ticks (there are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond) from 0001-01-01.

Many systems including Python `time` module use Unix *epoch* which started at 1970-01-01. You can use `time.time()` to see how many seconds elapsed from start of the epoch. It is floating point number.

In Java and in Jython you can use `System` methods like `currentTimeMillis()` and `nanoTime()`:

```
# this will work in Python/Jython/IronPython
import time
print(time.time())

# this will work in Jython
from java.lang import System
print(System.currentTimeMillis())
print(System.nanoTime())
```

If you need this as "wall" clock then use `time.time()`, convert it to ticks by multiplying it by 10000*1000 and adding ticks between 0001-01-01 and 1970-01-01.

If you need very precise difference between two events use `System.nanoTime()` (it has no connection with normal "wall clock" time).